# Some JS code Prevents POST Method How to Fix it

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I got some js code which is given in the below. It prevent POST Methods and Replace That method with GET how can i fix that ?

```
var form = $('#main-contact1-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Mail Gönderiliyor...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mesajınız başarı ile iletilmiştir. En kısa sürede tarafınıza dönüş yapılacaktır.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

When i look at in Developer Tool in Network, I got something about jquery.js. Is the jquery prevent to POST method?

[image: Screenshot]

[image: ScreenShot2]

Comment: But when i activate this i couldn't pass the value in php file with post method

Comment: Add `method: "POST"` in your ajax

Comment: Add action : post in your form

Comment: In my form action is already POST

Comment: Edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: I edited and share screen shot with you

Comment: How you determined the request is `GET` and not of `POST` type try using `var_dump($_POST)` in your php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `type: "POST"` in the `$.ajax` call. You're also missing the `data:` option to provide the POST parameters.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Mail Gönderiliyor...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mesajınız başarı ile iletilmiştir. En kısa sürede tarafınıza dönüş yapılacaktır.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Stil i got the GET Method.

Comment: Something else must be doing that, because this should work.

Comment: I'll add images to this post

Comment: No it's not inside of it

Comment: Well, it should be, like most jQuery event bindings.

Comment: So what can i do about it?

Comment: Is the rest of the submit handler running? Is it displaying the spinner?

Comment: I guess you have this code at the end of the HTML, so the DOM is loaded, is that right?

Comment: No not and of the html. I have a file main.js every code about ajax in it and Also sendemail.php that is the mail function

Comment: If you don't have the jQuery after the HTML, and it's not inside `$(document).ready()`, I don't see how it could possibly be binding the event handler correctly. Put the code inside `$(document).ready()`. That should be the first lesson of any jQuery tutorial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103802/discussion-between-kemal-ekren-and-barmar).

Comment: THANK YOU this is the answer that i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Add type parameter in your `$.ajax` function as below:

```
$.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Mail Gönderiliyor...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mesajınız başarı ile iletilmiştir. En kısa sürede tarafınıza dönüş yapılacaktır.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
```

Your form code is as follow:

`<form id="main-contact1-form" method="/Index.php" action="sendemail.php">`

Kindly change this to as below:

`<form id="main-contact1-form" method="POST" action="sendemail.php">`

Form method attribute will have the value as POST or GET not the file name
You can specify the file name in action attribute.

Comment: Still i got the GET Method.

Comment: This should work. Because this parameter means you wanted to send the ajax call via post method. Can you show your form code that you have build in HTML

Comment: I think jquery prevents POST methos.

Comment: No it should not. Can you show me your HTML code for form then I can help you for this.

Comment: site is papatyamasasandalyeler.com is the site check out the contact form in the bottom please

Comment: In the main code it already like that but when run the page it became like /index.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103804/discussion-between-alankar-more-and-kemal-ekren).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following modified code:

```
var form = $('#main-contact1-form');
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(){
                form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Mail Gönderiliyor...</p>').fadeIn() );
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Mesajınız başarı ile iletilmiştir. En kısa sürede tarafınıza dönüş yapılacaktır.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        });
    });
```

If `type` not mentioned it defaults to `GET`...

Comment: Stilll i got the GET Method.